# jk-Carousel is not behaving in proper manner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider, carousel

I am initializing my object in controller init() function.

Passing it to jk-carousel directive :

```
<jk-carousel data="dataArray" item-template-url="'item-template.html'"> </jk-carousel>
```

Now up there in dataArray there is array of objects and it is sliding properly with showing images in the given template url. And its the default exmaple as shown in link:
https://embed.plnkr.co/ovBExhpO40yzWPJ47QFE/

But again when i change the data model from "dataArray" to "dashboardsList" which is my actual object then component stops rendring properly only slides with empty page and never loaded the "item-template.html" tried it in many ways but still not working.
Any expert opinion will be appreciated!